# Google Assistant diverse behaviour on follow-up intents

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've developed an Action which uses the followup intent mechanism via a Cloud function.
I use the following line of code to fire the second intent:
`conv.followup("customEvent1");`
where `customEvent1` is the event I've set in the DialogFlow intent editor.
It works perfectly when I test it on the Actions Web simulator and also on Google Assistant app for my iPhone X.
Unfortunately Assistant on Android and on an iPhone XR does not understand the followup intent, so the Default Fallback Intent is fired.
How is it possible? How to solve it?

Comment: It *shouldn't* vary on the different devices this way. If you can update your question to include screen shots of the Intents in question, along with any logs, it may provide additional information. Seeing the additional code about how this gets called may also help, along with screen shots showing this happening on the devices.

Comment: @Prisoner thank you, I've updated the question with further details.

Comment: Thank you Prisoner, I found the problem... my ugly mistake, the alpha application was not published.....